# Has Path from pathlib a function which can check subfolders?

Tags: python, pathlib

I want to find all python files in a folder which are not located in a subfolder (e.g. `'.ipynb_checkpoints'`).

My current solution is

```
from pathlib import Path

rootdir = Path('/home/my_path')
# For absolute paths instead of relative the current dir
file_list = [
    f for f in rootdir.resolve().glob('**/*.py')
    if not '.ipynb_checkpoints' in str(f)
]
```

which gives me the correct list.

Neverteheless I was hoping that `pathlib` has some function like `f.includes()` or something similar.

Is there a soltion to generate the same list only using the functions of the `pathlib` package?

Comment: If the file must end with `.py`, why not include that in the glob? `'**/*.py'`.

Comment: is there ever going to be a file with a name like `.ipynb_checkpoints.py`? You might not need the `if` clause with the modified glob.

Comment: Not a big improvement, but there's also an `rglob` method which implicitly adds `**/` to the given pattern. `rooter.resolve().rglob('*.py')`.

Comment: @chepner Without the if condition if get some paths like `.../.ipynb_checkpoints/test_dummy.py`, and these files I want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prune the `.ipynb_checkpoints` directories from the search, I would use `os.walk`.

```
import os
import fnmatch
from pathlib import Path

file_list = []
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir.resolve()):
    # Select .py files from the current directory and create Path
    file_list.extend([Path(root, file) for file in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.py')])

    # In-place removal of checkpoint directories to prune them
    # from the walk.
    subdirs[:] = filter(lambda x: x != ".ipynb_checkpoints", subdirs)
```

From `os.walk`:

> When *topdown* is `True`, the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in *dirnames*; this can be used to prune the search,...